# Before_validation :foo, on: :update not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, object-lifetime

I'm using Rails 4.0.0. I have the following setup:

```rb
class Foo < ApplicationController

  before_validation :foo, on: :create

  ...

  private

    def bar
      puts 'bar is called'
    end
end
```

This works - in the console, when I create a `foo`, I see the message 'bar is called'. If I call `valid?` on `foo` the message is not called (correct behavior).

Now I want to add this callback also upon `update`. I've tried two things:

```
before_validation :foo, on: [:create, :update]
```

and

```
before_validation :foo, on: :create
before_validation :foo, on: :update
```

In both cases I see the following problem. In the console, if I instantiate a `foo` like so: `foo = Foo.last` and then call `foo.valid?`, I see the `bar` triggered, although I do not update the `foo`. I expect it to be called only after `foo.update(...)`. Am I doing something wrong or is this an expected behavior?

Comment: `before_validation :foo` or `before_validation :bar` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are assigning an **old record** into `foo` by `foo = Foo.last`, it will take `:update` as context while running the validations against `foo`. Where as, `on: :create` validations are only checked for **new record**.

If you study the [`valid?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F) method implementation, it will be clear:

```
def valid?(context = nil)
  context ||= (new_record? ? :create : :update)
  output = super(context)
  errors.empty? && output
end
```

Hope this helps.